# at jobs don't clear the queue even when completed?

Tags: linux, cron, queue, at

I have some very simple python code that sets up a job queue, piping to the linux `batch` command:

```
import subprocess

for j in range(1,17):
  process = subprocess.Popen('/bin/sh', '-c', f'python test.py {j} | batch')
  process.communicate()
  print(process.returncode)
```

When I run this, the `print(process.returncode)` line prints `0` which means success.

The script being called in the subprocess, `test.py`, just writes a quick txt file so nothing resource consuming:

```
import sys

with open(f'{sys.argv[1]}.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('hello')
```

This code creates 16 jobs and appears to run them all at once (`batch` is kinda pointless in what I'm doing at the moment since the server never reaches a load where it needs to queue jobs, but I'm just learning right now). Immediately after running it, when I type `atq` in the terminal, I can see that none of the jobs are running (no `=` or `b`), but they also don't clear the queue despite the seeming success given that they write the text files and give me a returncode of `0`. What could be the reason for them to not clear the queue? If it's a hidden error, how would I go about getting that output?

```
57      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
48      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
58      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
49      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
56      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
60      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
51      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
59      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
50      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
55      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
54      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
47      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
52      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
61      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
53      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
62      Wed Aug 16 18:37:00 2023
...
```